# Why does this variable refuse to work like a string?

Tags: php, wordpress, string

I am running the following line of code in WordPress' functions.php:

`$comment_meta_val = get_comment_meta($num_id, $comment_meta_key, true);`

When I set

```
$num_id = '76'
```

The code works perfectly. However, instead of '76' if I feed it a variable e.g. $comment_id, it doesn't work, even though I can echo $comment_id and see it is 76.

I've tried using

```
$num_id = strval($comment_id);
$num_id = (string) $comment_id;
$num_id = "$comment_id";
```

But none of the above work. It's probably something really stupid I'm doing wrong, but I've been up against this for the better part of the day and finally must accept I need help!

Comment: How are you setting `$comment_id`?

Comment: It's being passed in the function declaration
function custom_notificaion($notify_message, $comment_id) {

Comment: `var_dump($num_id)` or use a debugger to see the value and type when it isn't working

Comment: Just ran a quick test - interestingly, $comment_id is already passed as a string!

Comment: But then that's even more confusing, why wouldn't it be working if I pass it as $comment_id, but works when I set it as '76', even though when I echo $comment_id, I see it's 76

Comment: @FarhadD make a try with `trim()` like `$num_id = trim("$comment_id");`. not sure it'll work or not but your $comment_id may contain spaces

Comment: @don'tangryme didn't work, unfortunately

Comment: could you plz `var_dump($comment_id)` and show us what is inside it?

Comment: The function is meant to send an email @don'tangryme so I tried $noticeText .= var_dump($comment_id); where $noticeText is the email contents, but that didn't do anything

Comment: what is the length of that string?

Comment: 3 - presumably because it's now up to comment number 101

Comment: `$noticeText .= var_export($comment_id, true);`

Comment: '102' - that's what it emailed me

Comment: Let's step back a second: What exactly are you expecting to happen, and what are you observing that makes you believe it didn't work exactly as designed?  I'm starting to think your expectation or understanding of what `get_comment_meta()` is and how it works may be out of alignment with what it actually does.

Comment: Hi @dossy The function is built to customise the standard WP comment email notification, so that it also includes the values set by 2 custom fields in the comment meta. FYI: I have included fields to approve the post text and image along with the standard comment box.These work perfectly, and when comments are posted, I can see the Approved (Yes / No) fileds with the comment text. But not in the email.

Comment: At this point I think I'll need to see more of the surrounding code because it seems like the problem is elsewhere.  Sorry.

Comment: Any suggestions / guesses where I might start looking for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the action hook that was saving the metadata of a comment.
I had to add a new action in, which populates the comment meta into an array, and runs before the function I mentioned in my question.